# Angular2 async pipe with observable

Tags: asynchronous, angular, rxjs, observable

I try to consume an observable through an async pipe, here is my template :

```
<input #address type="text" id="address" placeholder="{{placeHolder}}" (keyup)="addTerm(address.value)" /> 
            <div *ngFor="let place of possiblesPlaces | async">
            {{place.label}}
</div>
```

Here is the component part :

```
    export class LocationFieldComponent implements OnInit{
    private searchTerms = new Subject<string>();

    @Input()
    placeHolder:string;


    possiblesPlaces:Observable<Array<{label:string,value:any}>>;

    addTerm(address:string) {
        this.searchTerms.next(address);
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {

        this.possiblesPlaces=this.searchTerms.filter(t=>t.length>2).debounceTime(300).distinctUntilChanged()
            .flatMap(term =>

                Observable.of(this.fetchResults(term))
             )
            .catch(error => {
            // TODO: real error handling
            console.log(error);
            return Observable.of([]);
        });
        this.possiblesPlaces.subscribe(val => console.log(val))
    }


    fetchResults(address:string) :Array<{label:string,value:any}> {
        var result=new Array;
        var geocoder  = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        console.log("search with"+address);
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, (results, status) => {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                for(let i=0;i<results.length;i++){
                    result.push( {label:results[i].formatted_address,value:null});
               }
            } else {
                console.log("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
            }
        });
        return result;
    }
}
```

I can see all the new values of the possiblesPlaces oberservable on the console but the async pipe won't show any results.

Sometimes i can see the results of the previous observable value for half a second when typing a new letter in the address field, i don't understand why?

**EDIT:** i discovered if i wait like 20 seconds, the results appear correctly. The request to the google api is quick but the async pipe seems to take a while. Any ides?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```ts
fetchResults(address:string) :Array<{label:string,value:any}> {
    var subj = new Subject();
    var geocoder  = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    console.log("search with"+address);
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, (results, status) => {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            for(let i=0;i<results.length;i++){
                subject.next( {label:results[i].formatted_address,value:null});
           }
        } else {
            console.log("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    });
    return subj.asObservable();
}
```

```ts
ngOnInit(): void {

    this.possiblesPlaces=this.searchTerms.filter(t=>t.length>2).debounceTime(300).distinctUntilChanged()
        .flatMap(term =>

            this.fetchResults(term).scan([], acc, x) => acc.concat(x));
         )
        .catch(error => {
        // TODO: real error handling
        console.log(error);
        return Observable.of([]);
    });
    this.possiblesPlaces.map(val => console.log(val))
}
```

`fetchResults()` returns an observable. In your question you return an empty array and then only fill it later when the response from Geocoder arrives. That doesn't look too reliable.

`ngOnInit()` uses `this.possiblePlaces.subscribe()` but `subscribe` returns a `Subscription` not an `Observable` and `| async` only works with `Promise` and `Observable` but not with `Subscription`. If you use `map` instead of `subscribe` an `Observable` is returned.

Comment: Thanks. it's helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

Ok i figured out!

You can"t use http request like geocoder.geocode which use a callback function, you have to deal with the angular way using http.get with an url